# Irony Language Toolkit - FreeTextLiteral usage

Tags: c#, irony

We have some special requirements around text templating that cannot be solved via any of the common packages (T4, NVelocity, StringTemplate..). So we have decided to attempt our own, using Irony.

Given the simple form where anything inside <%%> tags is an expression, otherwise just a text literal:

```
Hi <% u.FirstName %> This is some template text.
```

I started with this:

```
// Terminals
var text = new FreeTextLiteral("FreeTextLiteral", FreeTextOptions.AllowEof | FreeTextOptions.ConsumeTerminator, "<");
text.Escapes.Add(@"\<", "<");

var identifierTerminal = new IdentifierTerminal("identifierTerminal");
var expressionStart = new KeyTerm("%", "ExpressionStart");
var expressionEnd = new KeyTerm("%>", "ExpressionEnd");

// Non terminals
var statement = new NonTerminal("Statement");
var template = new NonTerminal("Template", typeof(StatementListNode));
var expression = new NonTerminal("Expression", typeof(ExpressionListNode));
var memberExpression = new NonTerminal("MemberExpression");

// Rules              
statement.Rule = text | expression;
expression.Rule = expressionStart + memberExpression + expressionEnd;
memberExpression.Rule = identifierTerminal + "." + identifierTerminal;
template.Rule = MakePlusRule(template, null, statement);
```

The issue is that checking the root node after parsing the extract above, there are two child nodes, both of them are **freetextliteral** nodes.

How do I prevent the Freetextliteral from consuming all input?

Thanks!